# Countries: A list of their state/province and cities list

Tags: django, python-2.7, mysql-python

I want to get all the countries, their states/province and cities in the world.

Where can I find this information?

Somebody please help me. I have searched many times, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [django-cities](https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities) which provides a list of countries and cities of the world. You will need to use http://www.geonames.org/ to import their database. Alternatively, you can directly download their database (in text format) and extract the values you need.

Comment: To get all cities with a population > 5000 get http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities5000.zip

Comment: when i syncdb i got this error  import name GEOSException.If you dont mind could you please help me.@arocks

Comment: Would need to see your full stack trace. Can you post the steps you followed and the error as a separate question?

Comment: Dont feel bad of me.I couldnt post this question.First i install dajngo-cities using this command `sudo pip install django-cities`.And then i copy that downloaded folder to my project directory.@arocks
And then i added cities to **insatalled_apps**.
Then i did **syncdb** and i got this error. 

    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException
    ImportError: cannot import name GEOSException

How can i solve this.

Comment: You need to follow some more installation steps to setup Geo Django as mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#ref-gis-install

Comment: I have seen many option in this "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#ref-gis-install" .I couldn't understand what to install. @arocks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Yahoo's GeoPlanet API.

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/api-reference.html#api-countries

The more specifically relevant portions are on

```
/countries/
/counties/{state}
```

There are even examples on how to retrieve entire list of countries on the page. Based on the state, you can also retrieve counties.

Additional:

If you are more specifically looking to do geocoding, you can try Google Maps Geocoding API located below:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=fr

This will allow you to get region specific information on your location of interest.

Comment: How can i add this to my project.I am new to django and i don't know how to connect API to my project .If you don't mind could you please help me? How can i implement this in my project? @DanGar

Comment: http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/states/US?appid=[yourappidhere]..Here what is this appid=[yourappidhere] .How can i connect this with my project? @DanGar